# How does the Laplace transformation transform a function from the time domain to the frequency domain?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, laplace-transform

I have just started learning about the Laplace transform, and our professor said that it transforms a function on the time domain to a function on the frequency domain.

The definition we had is the following

$$\mathcal{L} \{ f(t) \}=F(s)= \int_{0}^\infty f(t)e^{-st}dt$$
where $s$ is a real number.

I understand how $s=\sigma+i\omega$  could represent complex frequency, where $\omega$ is the angular frequency and $\sigma$ represents exponential decay or growth.

But if we limit $s$ to be only a real variable, then what does it mean for the Laplace operator to transform a function from time domain to frequency domain?

Comment: It is exactly as you say. In mathematics it is pointless to argue with someone who likes to call $s$ a frequency regardless if it is complex, purely imaginary, or even real. Calling it frequency does not hurt. Is $s$-domain any better?

Comment: I believe the Fourier transform is more commonly thought of as transforming the time domain to the frequency domain. There are various definitions of the Fourier transform, but if one defines the Fourier transform as
$$\mathcal{F}_t[f(t)](\omega)=\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty } f(t)\, e^{-i \omega t} \, dt$$ then it is equivalent to the bilateral Laplace transform $$\mathcal{B}_t[f(t)](s)=\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty } f(t)\, e^{-s t} \, dt$$ evaluated at $s=i \omega$.